# Node.js/AngularJS: Shrink image files to specific file size

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Using a MEAN environment, I would like to automatically shrink image files (.gif/.png/.jpg) which are uploaded by websites users, to a specific file size (e.g. 2 MB). 
Is there any node.js module available, enabling me to use something like this:

```
SomeModule.shrinkImage('MyHugeImage.jpg','2MB')
.then()
[...]
```

Apart from graphicsmagick minify function (where I have to calculate the minify factor on-the-fly based on the desired file size), I haven't found anything out-of-the box yet. May happen on client (using AngularJS) or server-side (Node.js module), I don't care. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I think [ng-image-resize](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-image-resize) can help you.

- Add this module to your project with bower or npm.

  eg: bower install angular-images-resizer.
- Include it in your app.

  angular.module('app', ['images-resizer']);
- Then simply add the service to your code and start resizing your images :

  `angular.module('app', function ($document, $log, $scope, resizeService) {
    resizeService
      .resizeImage('resources/imageToResize', {
          size: 100, 
          sizeScale: 'ko'
          // Other options ...
      })
      .then(function(image){

        // Add the resized image into the body
        var imageResized = document.createElement('img');
        imageResized.src = image;
        $document[0].querySelector('body').appendChild(imageResized);
      })
      .catch($log.error); 
      // Always catch a promise :)`

Please visit https://github.com/FBerthelot/angular-images-resizer for more details.